# How do I create a subgraph of one network using the edges and vertices of another network to calculate closeness centrality?

Tags: r, network-analysis

I have two networks, one for direct contiguity between countries, and one colonial network. I have matched the names of the vertices of both networks, and I can extract the edges from the colonial network using the incident() function from the igraph package. My problem is that I can't create a subgraph in the contiguity network using the colonial edges while keeping the vertex I used in the incident function. My aim is to find the closeness centrality of the colonial subnetworks in the contiguity network.

This is what I have done to try to create 3 colonial subnetworks and calculate their closeness centrality in the other network.

```
# Extracting the vertices from the colonial network
FRN_edges <- incident(col_net, "FRN", mode = "all")
GMY_edges <- incident(col_net, "GMY", mode = "all")
UKG_edges <- incident(col_net, "UKG", mode = "all")

# Creating the subgraph of the contiguity network using the colonial network edges
FRN_sub <- subgraph(cont_net, FRN_edges)
GMY_sub <- subgraph(cont_net, GMY_edges)
UKG_sub <- subgraph(cont_net, UKG_edges)


# Closeness centrality attempts

closeness(cont_net, vids = UKG_edges, mode = "all")
closeness(cont_net, vids = FRN_edges, mode = "all")
closeness(cont_net, vids = GMY_edges, mode = "all")


closeness(UKG_sub, mode = "all")
closeness(FRN_sub, mode = "all")
closeness(GMY_sub, mode = "all")
```

Although I get results for closeness centrality, they seem really low, and only the UKG calculation actually includes the UKG vertex, while the other two don't. Is there a way to include the original vertex? Or is there a better way to calculate closeness centrality for this case?